# Sum Field in MS Access Form Based in two criteria selected

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, sum

I created a query for my KPI with "Team", "Month", "Percentage Passed" as my key data.
What I am trying to execute now, is to have the sum of "Percentage Passed" per Team (i have 4 Teams) in a text box based on a selected month

I created a Split form that includes my key data & added text boxes per team where I want my sum up percentage appear & a Text Box to be used as search field for the month.

I am trying to create a VBA to this that is similar to Dlookup function but it was not successful.
Can someone please help me how can i execute this?

SQL in my Query

```
SELECT 
    [OE Finance Tracker].Team, 
    [OE Finance Tracker].ERP, 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Data Object], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Business Code], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Company Code], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Select], 
    Format([MNT Completion Date],"yyyymm") AS [Month], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Transaction Type], 
    IIf([Line Item Passed After Validation]<[Total Line Items Raised],[Total Line Items Raised],[Line Item Passed After Validation]) AS [Line Items], 
    IIf([Line Item Passed After Validation]<>[APP - Line Items Passed after Validation],[APP - Line Items Passed after Validation],IIf([MNT - Line Items Passed after validation]<>[Line Item Passed After Validation],[MNT - Line Items Passed after validation],[Line Item Passed After Validation])) AS [M15 Passed], 
    ([M15 Passed]/[Line Items]*100) AS [M15 Percentage], 
    IIf([M2Req]="0","0",IIf([M2App]="0","0",IIf([M2MNT]="0","0",[Line Items]))) AS [M2 Passed], 
    ([M2 Passed]/[Line Items]*100) AS [M2 Percentage], 
    IIf(IsNull([M16 Failure Reason]),[Line Items],"0") AS [M16 Passed], 
    ([M16 Passed]/[Line Items]*100) AS [M16 Percentage], 
    IIf([M15 Failure Reason - APP]<>"",[M15 Failure Reason - APP],[M15 Failure Reason - MNT]) AS [M15 Failure Reason], 
    IIf([M15 Comments - APP]<>"",[M15 Comments - APP],[M15 Comments - MNT]) AS [M15 Specific], 
    IIf([M2Req]="0",[M2 Failure Reason - REQMRD Lead],IIf([M2App]="0",[M2 Failure Reason - APP],IIf([M2MNT]="0",[M2 Failure Reason - MNT],""))) AS [M2 Failure Reason], 
    IIf([M2Req]="0",[M2 Comments - REQ/MRD Lead],IIf([M2App]="0",[M2 Comments - APP],IIf([M2MNT]="0",[M2 Comments - MNT],""))) AS [M2 Failure Specific], 
    IIf([M16 Failure Reason]<>"",[M16 Failure Reason]) AS [M16 Failure Reasons], 
    IIf([M16 Comments]<>"",[M16 Comments]) AS [M16 Failure Specifics], 
    IIf([Line Item Passed After Validation]<[Total Line Items Raised],[Total Line Items Raised],[Line Item Passed After Validation]) AS [Line ItemsM16], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Request Number], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Maintainer Assigned], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[MRD RequestorLead Assigned], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Approver Assigned], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Total line items Processed], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[APP - Line Items Passed after Validation], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[MNT - Line Items Passed after validation], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Total Line Items Raised], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Request Type], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Mantainer Status], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[Line Item Passed After Validation], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M2 Failure Reason - REQMRD Lead], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M2 Comments - REQ/MRD Lead], 
    IIf(IsNull([M2 Failure Reason - REQMRD Lead]),[Line Items],"0") AS M2Req, 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M15 Failure Reason - APP], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M15 Comments - APP], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M2 Failure Reason - APP], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M2 Comments - APP], 
    IIf(IsNull([M2 Failure Reason - APP]),[Line Items],"0") AS M2APP, 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M15 Failure Reason - MNT], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M15 Comments - MNT], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M2 Failure Reason - MNT], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M2 Comments - MNT], 
    IIf(IsNull([M2 Failure Reason - MNT]),[Line Items],"0") AS M2MNT, 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M16 Failure Reason], 
    [OE Finance Tracker].[M16 Comments] 
FROM 
    [OE Finance Tracker] 
WHERE 
    ((([OE Finance Tracker].[Request Type])="Request") AND 
    (([OE Finance Tracker].[Mantainer Status])="Completed"));
```

Comment: Hi Lois, could you include your SQL, example data and perhaps a screen shot, please?

Comment: Hi Paul, I didn't try SQL since I am not really good at it. what I tried is vba: TEAM1 = Sum("[Percentage Passed]", "KPI", "[SelMonth]='" & Me.Month & "'", "[Team]" = "Team1") (SelMonth is my searchbox for Month & "KPI" is my Query)

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58407759/edit) your question and put your code in there - anything that handles the process.

Comment: Hi Lois, if you edit your query, and where you'd normally click the **View** button on the very left of the ribbon, click the little arrow beside it and select **SQL**, then copy the SQL and paste into your question.

Comment: It's not too long - just copy it and paste it into the editor and I'll tidy it up for you.

Comment: Lois, please click the edit button just under your question (where it says **share edit close flag**) and paste your SQL into the question, not the comments.

Comment: so stupid of me. I just thought of that

Comment: Don't worry :o)

Comment: Hi Paul, the [M15 Percentage] is the field i want to sum based on selected Month in my Form

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code, and (now having the two pieces of code listed) I can safely say that your VBA is looking for `SelMonth` in your query.  Try the following...

```sql
TEAM1 = DSum("[Percentage Passed]", "KPI", "[Month]=""" & Me.SelMonth & """ AND [Team] = """ & Team1 & """")
```

You had the following issues...

1. You used [`Sum`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sum-data-by-using-a-query-430a669b-e7fd-4c4b-b154-8c8dbbe41c8a) instead of [`DSum`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32). `Sum` is the function that totals columns in the query itself, whereas `DSum` is an aggregate function for VBA.
2. You were testing `[SelMonth]` as a field in the query, rather than a value on your form.
3. You'd done something strange with the `Team` field, and it was referencing a fixed value of 'Team1'.

Personally, I believe that you've chosen the wrong way to do this.  You'd be far better off basing your form on a new query that only pulls the required data.  That query could be as simple as...

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM([M15 Passed]/[Line Items]*100) AS [M15 Percentage]
FROM 
    [OE Finance Tracker] 
WHERE 
    ((([OE Finance Tracker].[Request Type])="Request") AND 
    (([OE Finance Tracker].[Mantainer Status])="Completed")) AND 
    ((Format$([OE Finance Tracker].[MNT Completion Date], "yyyymm")) = Forms![MyForm]![txtMonth]) AND 
    (([OE Finance Tracker].[Team]) = Forms![MyForm]![txtTeam]);
```

But I'll leave that up to you.

There are still some confusing issues - using `TEAM1` to store your value is also a touch shaky.  Try researching [crosstab queries](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) to get your answers for **all** teams in one go.